# Configuring the hang detection policy by Jython

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I would like to create a dockerfile for WebSphere application server, to  config the hang detection policy by Jython script.

And I tried:

```
AdminServerManagement.configureCustomProperty('DefaultNode01', 'server1', 'Administration', 'com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.interval', '600');
```

but failed with error:

```
ADMG0007E: The configuration data type Administration is not valid.
```

However only UI steps are provided in the [Websphere knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ttrb_confighangdet.html). Anyone knows how to perform this by scripting?

Comment: the third argument (parentType) should just be 'server'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @covener, parentType 'Server' works.

```
wsadmin> AdminServerManagement.configureCustomProperty('DefaultNode01', 'server1', 'Server','com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.interval', '600');
---------------------------------------------------------------
 AdminServerManagement:  Configuring custom Property
 nodeName:               DefaultNode01
 serverName:             server1
 parentType:             Server
 propertyName:           com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.interval
 propertyValue:          600
 Optional Attributes:
     otherAttributeList  []
 Usage: AdminServerManagement.configureCustomProperty("DefaultNode01", "server1", "Server", "com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.interval", "600")
 Return: If the command is successful, a value of 1 is returned.
---------------------------------------------------------------

[description "The frequency, in seconds, at which managed threads in the selected application serv-er will be interrogated."]
[name com.ibm.websphere.threadmonitor.interval]
[required false]
[value 600]
```